# Django query object filter

Tags: django, database, forms, view

I'm trying to get all objects from my DB that meet specified conditions. From my model `Training` I need to get all objects that are connected with logged user, date is in specified range and type of training is specified.
Model:

```
class Training(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    length = models.TimeField()
    distance = models.FloatField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=TRAINING_TYPE)
    caloriesBurnt = models.FloatField()
    weight = models.FloatField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=25)
```

View with filters:

```
def ReportRequest(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReportForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            usrname = request.user
            q = Training.objects.filter(user=usrname)
            q = Training.objects.filter(date__range=[form.cleaned_data['start'], form.cleaned_data['end']])
            q = Training.objects.filter(type=form.cleaned_data['type'])
            quantity = q.count
            if quantity == 0:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/notrainings/')
            avg_length = q.aggregate(Avg('length'))
            avg_distance = q.aggregate(Avg('distance'))
            avg_calories = q.aggregate(Avg('caloriesBurnt'))
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/report/')
        else:
            return render_to_response('reportform.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = ReportForm()
        return render_to_response('reportform.html',{'form':form}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

And form in which user sets data range and type of training:

```
class ReportForm(forms.Form):
    start = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(), initial=date.today())
    end = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(),initial=date.today())
    type = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=ACTIVITY_CHOICES, initial=RUNNING)
```

My problem: in my DB all trainings were made 9th and 10th December. When I set date range in my form from 2nd to 3rd Dec it should redirect me to `/notrainings/`. But it doesn't. No matter if I use `quantity = q.count` or `quantity = q.count()`. 
I would greatly appreciate help with this topic.

**Solved, thanks to both Mihai & ruddra**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is easy. You are querying the `Training` always, you don't store your partial results. The last query that gets stored is this one:

`q = Training.objects.filter(type=form.cleaned_data['type'])`

So actually you are only filtering function of `type`

What you should do is this:

```
q = Training.objects.filter(user=usrname) 
q = q.filter(date__range=[form.cleaned_data['start'], form.cleaned_data['end']]) 
q = q.filter(type=form.cleaned_data['type'])
```

or if you want all at once:

```
q = Training.objects.filter(
    user=usrname,
    date__range=[form.cleaned_data['start'], form.cleaned_data['end']],
    type=form.cleaned_data['type'],
)
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, but right now if I enter any date (good/bad), I'm being redirected to `reportform` with error `AttributeError at /reportform
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects'`
Problem is with this line: `q = q.objects.filter(date__range=[form.cleaned_data['start'], form.cleaned_data['end']])`

Comment: sorry, I have edited my response. You don't have to type ``objects`` again now. ``q`` is not a model anymore, the manager has been accessed. So try now :)

Comment: Now it takes me to `report` if I put wrong dates again, not to `notrainigs` as it should. My code looks like this now:

`q = Training.objects.filter(user=usrname)
            q = q.filter(date__range=[form.cleaned_data['start'], form.cleaned_data['end']])
            q = q.filter(type=form.cleaned_data['type'])`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this like:

```
q = Training.objects.filter(user=usrname).filter(date__range=[form.cleaned_data['start'], form.cleaned_data['end']]).filter(type=form.cleaned_data['type'])

count = q.count()
```